# Can Java MVC pattern be combined with a delegate pattern?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, delegates

I am currently studying MVC and delegate pattern in one of my classes. I know that the MVC requires 4 classes to make it run. Is it possible to have a delegate combined with an MVC, or is that unconventional?

Comment: 4 classes? Model, View, Controller and Surprise class?

Comment: Where is it written that MVC requires 4 classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most frameworks MVC (struts, spring mvc for example) are really a combination of MVC and delegate.

Infact you have a single point of entry the Servlet (often named dispatcher) that delegates the control to the Control classes

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  The Servlet is the dispatcher (not a controller).